# Xtend import error in Junit test case

Tags: eclipse, junit, xtend

I am attempting to write a test case in Xtend using Junit 5 on Eclipse Oxygen. A screenshot of the Eclipse Java perspective shows the source code and the environment:

[image: Java perspective]

Here is a screenshot for the build properties for the project:

[image: Build Properties]

I am using Maven in this project as well.
Can anyone suggest what I need to doto be able to compile and run my test case?

Comment: I have issues like this all the time. Generally I just have to rebuild, clean and restart eclipse a couple times and it works lol

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but just I had the same issue so I'm posting this answer in case it's useful for anybody.

In the properties window, select **Java Build Path** (your second screenshot), then click on the tab "Source".
For the generated test sources, for example `xtend-gen` folders, toggle the option "Contains test sources" to be `true`. Then, set the option "Output folder" with the value `target/test-classes`.
When you apply the changes you your build should go back to normal.